# How to extract particular data in a line using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file contains lines like:

```
754.82915: MODE1(0, 0x001900, 0x00090)
754.82916: MODE2(0, 0x001900, 0x00090)
```

How to take the data from "(" to ")" in python??.

I tried the code:

```
fo=open("file1.txt","r")
fin=open("file2.txt","w")
lines=fo.readlines()
for line in lines:
    result=re.search(r'\(.*\)', line)
    res="\n"+result.group()
    fin.write(res)
fo.close()
```

It showing following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: That's the exact content of your text file? (May be you've some empty lines as well)

Comment: [`re.search(pattern, string, flags=0)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search): Return None if no position in the string matches the pattern; note that this is different from finding a zero-length match at some point in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sticking to your original code, just add one line to check whether `result` is `None`.

```
with open("file1.txt","r") as fin:
    lines = fin.readlines()
    with open("file2.txt","w") as fout:
        for line in lines:
            result = re.search(r'\(.*\)', line)
            if result:     # check if not None
                res = "\n" + result.group()
                fout.write(res)
```

You should also learn from @Peter's more pythonic answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using the `with` statements and the `findall()` function of the `re` module, like this:

```
import re

with open('file1.txt', 'r') as fin:
    with open('file2.txt', 'w') as fout:
        fout.write('\n'.join(re.findall(r'\(.*\)', fin.read())))
```